# Print multiple choice solutions dynamically

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, exam

I trying to figure out how to print the multiple choice answers of my exam paper dynamically using the tikz package.

This is what I have so far:

```
\documentclass{exam}

\usepackage{tikz}

\newcounter{solcount}
\setcounter{solcount}{1} 
\newcommand{\CC}{\CorrectChoice\label{sol:\arabic{solcount}}\stepcounter{solcount}}
\newcommand\MCanswers{\section*{\centering {\textbf{{\LARGE Multiple Choice Solutions}}}}
    \foreach \x in {1,...,10}{\centering\noindent \x.~\ref{sol:\x}\par }}

\newcommand{\emptybox}[2][\textwidth]{% Empty Box
    \begingroup
    \setlength{\fboxsep}{-\fboxrule}%
    \noindent\hspace*{-5mm}\framebox[#1]{\rule{0pt}{#2}}%
    \endgroup
}

\begin{document}

\begin{questions}
\question[1] What is $1+1$? 
\begin{choices} \choice 1 \CC 2 \choice 3 \choice 4 \end{choices}

\question[1] What is $2+1$? 
\begin{choices} \choice 1 \choice 2 \CC 3 \choice 4 \end{choices}

\question[1] What is $2+2$? 
\begin{choices} \choice 1 \choice 2 \choice 3 \CC 4 \end{choices}


\end{questions}

\MCanswers
\end{document}
```

It produces the following:
[image: Output 1]

The problem is, I don't want to see question 4-10 as ??. I need to be more dynamic such that if I have 3 questions, it will print the solutions to my 3 questions and so on.

I know the problem is here:

```
\foreach \x in {1,...,10}{\centering\noindent \x.~\ref{sol:\x}\par }}
```

But I'm not sure how to go about making {1,... \numquestions} work?

Comment: Replace `\foreach \x in {1,...,10}` by `\foreach \x in {1,...,\the\numexpr\value{solcount}-1\relax}`.

Comment: P.S. Do not use `\section*{\centering...`. Instead use a package like `titlesec` to format the sections.

Comment: thanks for that. works like a charm!

Comment: @user272921 - I would argue that using \centering on a title is better than inflicting titlesec on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simplify the code by incrementing `solcount` before using it instead of after.

In case you are interested, an alternative to using `\label` and `\ref` is `\csname ...\endscnane` and `\xdef`.   The `\expandafter` is to allow `\csname` to expand the macro name before running `\xdef`.  While normally one cannot add numbers to macro names, `\csname` can use almost anything.

The advantage is that it works on the first run.  The disadvantage is that you can't put `\MCanswers` before the questions.

```
\documentclass{exam}

\usepackage{tikz}

\newcounter{solcount}% set to 0

\newcommand{\CC}{\CorrectChoice\stepcounter{solcount}%
  \expandafter\xdef\csname sol.\thesolcount\endcsname{\thechoice}}
\newcommand\MCanswers{\section*{\centering{\textbf{{\LARGE Multiple Choice Solutions}}}}
    \foreach \x in {1,...,\thesolcount}{\centering \x.~\csname sol.\x\endcsname\par }}

\newcommand{\emptybox}[2][\textwidth]{% Empty Box
    \begingroup
    \setlength{\fboxsep}{-\fboxrule}%
    \noindent\hspace*{-5mm}\framebox[#1]{\rule{0pt}{#2}}%
    \endgroup
}

\begin{document}

\begin{questions}
\question[1] What is $1+1$? 
\begin{choices} \choice 1 \CC 2 \choice 3 \choice 4 \end{choices}

\question[1] What is $2+1$? 
\begin{choices} \choice 1 \choice 2 \CC 3 \choice 4 \end{choices}

\question[1] What is $2+2$? 
\begin{choices} \choice 1 \choice 2 \choice 3 \CC 4 \end{choices}


\end{questions}

\MCanswers
\end{document}
```